# What does this function in OCaml do?

Tags: ocaml

What does this function do in OCaml?

```
let rec pack xs = 
  match xs with 
  | [] -> [] 
  | [x] -> [[x]]
  | first :: second :: rest -> 
    if first = second then 
      let (firstC :: restC) = pack rest in 
      (first :: firstC) :: restC 
    else 
      [first] :: pack rest
```

I especially am confused with the line:

```
let (firstC :: restC) = pack rest in 
(first :: firstC) :: restC
```

Answer (score 3):

The `let` expression in OCaml looks like this:

```
let <pattern> = <expr1> in <expr2>
```

In the expression you're asking about, the pattern is `firstC :: restC`. This is a pattern that matches any non-empty list. The first element of the list is bound to `firstC` and the rest of the list is bound to `restC`.

The pattern is matched against `expr1`, which in your case is `pack rest`. If `pack rest` returns a non-empty list, this gives values to `firstC` and `restC`.

These bindings are then used in the `expr2` of your example, which is:

```
(first :: firstC) :: restC
```

This is a list made by adding `first` to the beginning of the list `firstC` and then adding this list to the beginning of the list of lists `restC`.

If `pack rest` returns an empty list the result will instead be an exception.

Since `pack rest` can indeed return an empty list, this code looks fairly suspect to me. Here's an example where it fails in this way:

```
# pack [3; 3];;
Exception: Match_failure ("//toplevel//", 5, 54).
```

Note that compiler warns you that the pattern `firstC :: restC` doesn't cover every case. Hence it might produce an exception (which it does).

```
Warning 8 [partial-match]: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
```

I hope this is helpful.